# How to persist a value in jquery after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

The value from text_box is blanked after refresh page using jquery.
 Any suggestion ???

Comment: If you want the value to persist you'll probably want to send it to the server somehow (probably by submitting the form, though you could also use AJAX), then set the value of the input accordingly when generating the HTML for the reloaded page.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield no  doesnt want cookies to set the values..:) Thnaks

Comment: @AnthonyGrist : Yaa something like i hve to do:) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if i understand your question completely, but i guess you want something like following

```
<%= text_field_tag 'name', params[:some_param] ? params[:some_param] : nil %>
```

If you have some variable (say @instance_variable) and you want that value into the textfield use following

```
<%= text_field_tag 'name', @instance_variable ? @instance_variable : nil %>
```

ref [`text_field_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002240)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) or [session storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)  or [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) to store values on client side and values will be available after refresh.

**Using local storage**

Before using web storage, check browser support for localStorage and sessionStorage:

```
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
{
     localStorage.lastname="Smith";
}
else
{
   // Sorry! No web storage support..
}
```